# What is the use of <mvc:annotation-driven />?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would first like to clarify that there are lots of discussion about this in stack overflow and other forums. I have read those and understood some concept behind `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. But the more I read the more I get confused. In some responses I have read that `<mvc:annotation-driven />` gives a support for `@ResponseBody`. But as I am a beginner I have installed sping-mvc-showcase application and found that there is extensive use of this annotation without use of `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. Can you please enlighten me on this?

Comment: There are a number of Spring Annotations relevant to Spring MVC. If you use these in your projects, you need to tell Spring to look for them by using the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you would set up support for using MVC annotations (and some other stuff) if you're using xml configuration of Spring MVC. With the newer versions of Spring MVC, you can instead configure your application with pure Java, and you can achieve the same by adding the annotation `@EnableWebMVC` to your configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMVC
public class MyConfig {
    // rest of config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC or for that matter any implementation of Spring can be configured in two ways Xml or Java-Based. Simply using the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag within your Xml configuration file means that you are specifying to Spring that you will be using Spring annotations which Spring has to look for in your Java-Based Programs that can be anything for example -

```
@Controller
public class index() {
 ...
}
```

will be registered as a Controller in Spring's Container when your application is initializing and Spring scans the base-package that you specify in your configuration.
Also annotations such as the

> "@EnableWebMvc"

Simply enables a wide range of classes that can be used which are quite useful and specifically designed to help develop MVC web applications using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

does more than enable you to used the MVC related annotations.
A look at [the schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd) will show that you can configure  HttpMessageConverters, HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers, HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlers, options for asynchronous request processing,FormattingConversionServices, JSR-303 Validator, ContentNegotiationManager,
MessageCodesResolver, and etc.

If you don't configure any of that yourself, it will provided defaults for you.

It only affects Servlet MVC.